# Obtain value from XML element using XML parser and assign it to a variable

Tags: xml, shell, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
             xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>BundleResourceDeploy</groupId>
        <artifactId>Project3</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>sbar</packaging>
        <description></description>
</project>
```

Also I have the following XSLT stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" exclude-result-prefixes="ns">

 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="ns:project">


  <xsl:element name="ns:groupId">
    <xsl:value-of select="ns:groupId"/>
  </xsl:element>

  <xsl:element name="ns:artifactId">
    <xsl:value-of select="ns:artifactId"/>
  </xsl:element>

  <xsl:element name="ns:version">
    <xsl:value-of select="ns:version"/>
  </xsl:element>

  <xsl:element name="ns:packaging">
    <xsl:value-of select="ns:packaging"/>
  </xsl:element>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Executing the command: xsltproc "stylesheet" "xml_file" > output.xml

The output (content of output.xml file) is:

```
<ns:groupId xmlns:ns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">BundleResourceDeploy</ns:groupId><ns:artifactId xmlns:ns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">Project2</ns:artifactId><ns:version xmlns:ns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">1.0-SNAPSHOT</ns:version><ns:packaging xmlns:ns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">sbar</ns:packaging>
```

What I want to achieve is:
In a shell script I want to obtain the value of the element "groupId", which would be "BundleResourceDeploy", and assign it to a variable.

Could you help me out with a way on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use XMLStarlet:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^-- NOT /bin/sh; process substitution is an extension in ksh and bash
#             $'' literal syntax is an extension as well, likewise read -d

IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' groupId artifactId version packaging < <(
  xmlstarlet sel \
    -N ns='http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0' \
    -t -m /ns:project \
    -v ns:groupId -n \
    -v ns:artifactId -n \
    -v ns:version -n \
    -v ns:packaging -n \
    <pom.xml && printf '\0'
)

echo "pom.xml is for $groupId/$artifactId, version $version, with packaging $packaging"
```

However, what the `xmlstarlet` command in that script actually does is entirely equivalent to a slightly different XSLT template, which you can ask XMLStarlet to generate for you by passing the `-C` argument:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/ns:project">
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="ns:groupId"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="ns:artifactId"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="ns:version"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="ns:packaging"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="value-of-template">
    <xsl:param name="select"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$select"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($select)[position()&gt;1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that we're not creating elements in our output here at all, but rather generating a textual stream delimited by newlines. (We'd need to adjust our approach if newlines could appear in our values, but that's not the case in a Maven POM).

---

If you were using the stylesheet I gave above, the exact script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' groupId artifactId version packaging \
   < <(xsltproc stylesheet.xslt pom.xml) && printf '\0')

echo "pom.xml is for $groupId/$artifactId, version $version, with packaging $packaging"
```

Comment: The xmlsh tool is another possibility to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Below a better option using `xmllint`. The example is a shell script which returns the value of the `<version/>` element:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'setns ns=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
cat /ns:project/ns:version/text()' | \
xmllint --shell pom.xml | egrep -v '^(/ >| -----)'
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `--shell` rather than `--xpath`? `--shell` is very much built for interactive use, hence doing things that aren't script-friendly like printing the prompt to stdout (and thus mixing prompt strings with extracted output).

Comment: ...using tools that are meant for interactive use programatically is risky, because interactive features aren't generally well-defined -- just because the prompt is `> ` in current versions doesn't mean it'll stay that in the future, for instance, so you have no guarantee that this code will continue to work. By contrast, the output of an XSLT processor is *entirely* well-defined, and can't change in any pertinent way without becoming noncompliant with the standard.

Comment: ...so, a safer way to do this with xmllint would be: `xmllint --xpath '/*[namespace-uri()="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" and local-name()="project"]/*[namespace-uri()="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" and local-name()="version"]/text()'`

Comment: (aside: part of the reason well-designed shells print their prompts to stderr rather than stdout is to avoid the category of problem you're having, and working around with `grep`, with `xmllint --shell` here).

Answer (score -2):

I managed to achieve it by working directly on the source XML file instead of working with xsltproc. In my shell script I created the following variable:

GROUPID="$(grep -Po '(?<=)\w+(?=)' name_of_xml_file_here"

Comment: Don't do that. It might work on one XML file but it will fail on the next, because you aren't allowing for all the variations that can legitimately occur in well-formed XML. You are storing up problems for the future.

Comment: Looking for better options I managed to solve it using xmllint. I will post it in another answer